# Node throws TypeError: Invalid URL for SQL Server connection string

Tags: node.js, sql-server, url

When I try to run this on the node REPL (Node.js v 18.4.1), I get the error mentioned:

`new URL('sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=mydb;user=sa;password=mySpiffyPassword;trustServerCertificate=true')`

The odd thing is, if I add a `@` to the end of the password (`mySpiffyPassword@`), it doesn't error.  (Though this isn't my db password, and so that will never do, obviously.)

Background: I happen to be trying to use the connection string in an app that uses Prisma, so I tried this in the node REPL, which worked just fine:

`new URL('sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=mydb;user=sa;password=r@ndomP@$$w0rd;trustServerCertificate=true')`

The URL came from [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/add-to-existing-project/relational-databases/connect-your-database-typescript-sqlserver).

I slow-walked the `r@ndomP@$$w0rd` value towards `mySpiffyPassword` and narrowed it down to the `@` character making the difference.  That led me to [this](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlobjectauth) in the Node docs, which mentioned the `@` character as well.

I tried doing

`new URL('sqlserver://sa:mySpiffyPassword@localhost:1433;database=mydb;trustServerCertificate=true')`

But that also threw the invalid URL error.

I know the connection string is valid (or at least correct), because I was able to run `npx prisma pull` using it and that worked just fine; Prisma connected and populated my `schema.prisma` file with all the tables from my db.  Prisma has nothing to do with the question - just mentioned it because it proves the URL was working - just not for Node's `new URL()` to be happy with it.

Comment: Oracle might call it a JDBC URL but it doesn't really conform to any of the RFCs that define URL/URI. It won't error if you put a `/` after the port number, but the parameters are then parsed into the URL's `.pathname` property.

Comment: I think you are hitting an issue with special characters and their escaping. The million dollar question is where. Also check parameter names e.g. "database=mydb" vs "databaseName=mydb"